# recognize_google do not work with sr.AudioData() in python

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I want to get an audio file in js and then send this file to python and then recognise the text being spoken. I know that tools exist in js, but I need server-side recognition in order to secure the interface in an online mini-game.
`main.js`

```
async function try_case(click) {
    var el = click.target;
    el.innerHTML = microphoneHtml;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].removeEventListener('click', try_case);
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(function(stream) {
            var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            var audioChunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function(event) {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            });
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function() {
                document.getElementsByClassName('micro-listener')[0].classList.add('exit');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    el.innerHTML = "";
                }, 500);
                var audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('audio', audioBlob);

                fetch(`/dashboard/games/memowordrize/${sessionID}/record`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
                        },
                        body: formData
                    })
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data);
                    });

            });
            setTimeout(function() {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            }, 3000);
        });

    return;
}
```

memowordrize.py

```
@memowordrize_bp.route('/dashboard/games/memowordrize/<string:session_id>/record', methods=['POST'])
@check_game
def record(session_id):
    try:
        if 'audio' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({
                "code": 403,
                "message": "Aucun fichier audio n'a été trouvé!",
                "result": []
            })
        audio_file = request.files['audio']
        audio_data = audio_file.read()
        
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        audio = sr.AudioData(audio_data, 16000, 2)
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")
        print(text)
        return jsonify({
            "code": 200,
            "message": "Le texte a été reconnu!"
        })
        

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error has occured: " + str(e))
        return jsonify({
            "code": 500,
            "message": "Une erreur s'est produite!",
            "result": []
        }), 500
```

Everything works (I didn't put in all my code), it's from the line `text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="fr-FR")` that an error is detected.

The error is captured but nothing is displayed to indicate: `ERROR:root:An error has occured:`. But nothing is indicated. No indication on the net or by chatGpt.

Comment: Can you log e by itself, logging.error(e), maybe str(e) is breaking e.

Comment: I've tried, but nothing appears. I did try sr.UnknownValueError, which catches the error, but that doesn't help either. The audio file is good, I even tried downloading it and it works.